# Add Color Settings To Wordpress Gutenberg Headers

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How do I add color settings to the Gutenberg Header block? I've added theme support for paragraphs with this...

```
function apache_theme_supported_features() {

    add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'One', '@@textdomain' ),
            'slug' => 'one',
            'color' => esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'one', '#e63946' ) ),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Two', '@@textdomain' ),
            'slug' => 'two',
            'color' => esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'two', '#97efe9' ) ),
        ),
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain, what do you mean by Gutenberg header block ? Is this a custom block or default block that comes with gutenberg ?

Comment: It's a default block that is a header/title instead of a paragraph block. Let me know if I can elaborate! I tried finding a reference, but couldn't see it. There's a lot about creating new blocks, not as much about editing core blocks.

Comment: Paste your full block code, so that more people can understand the problem better

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not supported by the new editor - while there are more and more support requests asking for it.

Yeah, one of the bad news related to the new WP editor.

The main support ticket is here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6012

Please comment it, upvote the comments and contribute to make this feature a high priority.